# Quel est le sens du mot "mordi" ?

Tags: sens, histoire, interjections

Je lis maintenant "La Reine Margot", et l'un des personnages s'écrie souvent "mordi !". Voici quelques exemples:

> — Mordi ! s’écria Coconnas, voici, sur ma foi ! un plaisant animal.
>
> — Mais il se moque de nous, s’écria Coconnas exaspéré, mordi !

Je n'arrive pas à trouver ce mot dans un dictionnaire. Qu'est-ce qu'il signifie? Est-ce qu'on utilise ce mot dans la langue française moderne?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Il s'agit certainement d'une variante du juron « Mordieu » qui apparaît d'ailleurs dans une réplique suivante:

> — Mordieu ! dit La Mole en pâlissant, y aurait-il déjà trahison ?

« Mordi » n'est plus du tout utilisé (ni reconnu) aujourd'hui.

Un juron proche plus courant est « morbleu » mais il n'est plus employé.

Comment: il s'agit d'une variante analogue à "pardi" pour dire "par dieu".

Answer (score 2):

Selon le contexte il semble qu'il s'agisse d'une interjection marquant l'ampleur du propos.

On peut voir ici d'autres exemples d'utilisation.

http://books.google.ca/books?id=k0Dmp74A8xMC&pg=PA57&lpg=PA57&ots=28N1JKwIkY&focus=viewport&dq=mordi+interjection&hl=fr&output=html_text

Voir comme explication:
"Dans ce dernier cas l’origine de la forme mardi peut s’expliquer de deux façons : soit par l’attraction paronymique qui amène mardi pour maudit, comme dans le cas de jeudi pour Jésus, soit par l’histoire dialectale du mot mordi qui proviendrait de mort de dieu."

http://fr.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/mautadi